# Catching events in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, event-handling

Does anyone know how to catch events in Mac OS X ? My problem is that I need to intercept for example a MOUSEKEYDOWN or maybe a KEYSTROKE before the event arrives to any application. My objective is to block the event or change the data it could contain. I read something about the kEvent class but I could not find some sample to understand how to begin programming with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Quartz Event Taps.  You can explore how they work with [Event Taps Testbench](http://pfiddlesoft.com/eventtapstestbench/) or read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can use the Carbon API to register to events ***and modify them***. Modifying the event is not possible if you use Cocoa, i.e. the NSEvent class, which can only be observed. I used [this](http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/adding-a-hotkey-listener/) tutorial to get started with the Carbon API myself. I found it really hard to find any tutorials not using Cocoa, so I hope that helps.